# Showing an error while i try to run a bash script

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a bash script named `hello`. I want to run this script using a Docker container. I made a `Dockerfile` and gave the following input:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/asthana/Desktop/DockerFiles
RUN chmod +x ./hello
RUN ./hello
```

Both the `hello` and `Dockerfile` are in same directory and is the current working directory. However there is an error showing up

```
chmod: cannot access './hello' : No such file or directory
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COPY` to copy the hello thing from host to container.

```
FROM ubuntu
COPY ./hello /hello
RUN chmod +x /hello && /hello
```